# Customs / Immigration formalities for Europe short vacation

Tags: europe, schengen, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, paperwork

I'll be travelling to Europe on a Schenegen visa for around 8 days.
The entry point would be France (Paris)
This would be my first international visit.
What are the general customs / immigration formalities that I'll need to do while travelling from India to France and on the return leg (Switzerland to India) ?

Answer (score 2):

The only formality you should pay attention to is making certain you get a Schengen exit stamp when leaving Switzerland. (You will get an entry stamp in France).

For the rest the formalities are pretty straightforward. When travelling to or from Switzerland you technically still have to pass customs (but not immigration) but in practice that border is as transparent as the other intra Schengen borders…

Comment: Travelling from France to Paris?!?

Comment: (+1) I took the liberty of editing your answer as I assume you meant traveling from Paris to Switzerland (I think the OP has a more complex trip in mind but your remark still applies).

Comment: Note that I have been asked about the goods I am carrying with me and even had a customs officer inspect a receipt from a French supermarket (she specifically asked if I had been shopping) when crossing the France/Switzerland border. Interestingly, the receipt was helpfully organized by category (and not by the order the items were scanned at the checkout as in just about any other supermarket in France) so it seems control do happen sufficiently frequently to motivate the local shops to make it easy to check the quantity of meat, dairy and alcohol…

Comment: You can indeed be asked about food. Especially when entering with a car with local license plates. My experience with crossing the Swiss border is mostly on trains, and there I have never been asked about goods, or even had to show my ID. And that even before Switzerland joined Schengen...

Comment: Well, it's all anecdotal of course but before Schengen I do remember quite extensive checks on (night) trains. For some reason, it also seems that the border with Germany has long been more strongly enforced than that with France.

Comment: I can confirm that custom checks when entering Switzerland are quite common. I also sincerely doubt that it was common practice before Switzerland joined Schengen to not having any immigration control on trains. Not so much because of the missing Swiss entry check, but because of the required immigration check when leaving the Schengen area. As you wrote yourself, non EU/EEC-nationals need an exit stamp when leaving the Schengen area. Otherwise they are likely to get into trouble when trying to enter the Schengen area later.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Your objection makes perfect sense and yet it really was that way, both before the Schengen area existed at all and after the Schengen agreement came into force but before Switzerland joined. Controls were far from systematic at small crossings on the road, for regional trains [like this one](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhone-Express-Regional#Rh.C3.B4ne_Express_R.C3.A9gional) or at pedestrian bridges over the Rhine or elsewhere. I guess the rationale that non-locals were unlikely to use those crossings and this was not a sensitive border but still.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Here is an example of how it looked like: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stein_AG_Holzbr%C3%BCcke_Zollschild.JPG?uselang=de (photo is from 2012 but I remember something similar around 2004-2005 at this particular place). I think there is/was an office on the German side but you had to go there yourself if you needed a stamp, the bridge itself was simply open.

Comment: Were these border crossings open for non-EU/EEC or Swiss citizens before Switzerland joined the Schengen area. With "open", I mean legal to use, not open in the sense of "noone will check you".

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I don't know, I don't think so but the discussion was really about the “noone will check you” aspect… The point being that if you need(ed) a stamp to avoid problems in the future, you had to go look for it yourself.

Comment: Incidentally, even at large crossings, Switzerland had a system under which you could use a special lane if you put a sign on your car that basically means “I know the rules and I am not importing anything illegal”. There could of course be controls, either for customs or for immigration purposes, but they were already very infrequent in practice at least since the 1980s I think. Speaking about the region around Geneva, by the time Schengen came, the French had already all but given up controls on the border itself except perhaps at a handful of large border crossings.